# Application icon in the windows status bar

Tags: java, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

When our eclipse rcp application launches, we are showing the login page (provided by the eclipse framework, but it is customized to our requirement). When the login page is being shown, the application icon in the windows status bar is not the icon that we have provided in our application, but instead it is the eclipse icon. When the login process is completed (on successful login), the icon in the status bar is getting updated to the icon that we have specified in our application.

How can i change the application icon to the icon provided by us when the login page is being displayed? we don't want to show the eclise icon.

Any pointers is much helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to set an image on the Shell object from the login page. Something like that:

```
FileInputStream fStream = new FileInputStream(new File("C:\\image.jpg"));   
Image image = new Image(display, fStream);
shell.setImage(image);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for the pointer. It works, now before the login page comes up, eclipse icon will be displayed for sometime. Is it possible to change that also?

Comment: Haven't tried that, but may be it works: http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_replace_the_Eclipse_workbench_window_icon_with_my_own%3F ("Simply check out the org.eclipse.platform plug-in from the Eclipse repository, and replace eclipse.gif with any other icon.")